# How can I populate links to paged entities in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-hateoas

I have a functioning `@RestController` backed by a JpaRepository with a JpaSpecificationExecutor.

My specification search is all working, and returns a `Page<MyEntity>`.  Unfortunately, the paged entities do not have any of their HAL links (e.g. _links, _extensions, etc.). Is there an easy way to add these links automatically to the paged search results?

I've found the occasional forum post references to `EntityLinks` and `linkToPagedResource()`, but haven't had any luck getting them to work.
`linkToPagedResource()` is not showing up when I add hateoas to the pom.xml, and I'm not finding any examples of its use, so it's unclear if it's even what I'm looking for.